# What does :tls => true do in SMTP settings in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, sendgrid-rails

I'm using Sendgrid on a Rails 5.2 application and was getting a
`Net::ReadTimeout` error when trying to send an email. The post here
https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/639#issuecomment-29016055 suggested adding `:tls => true` to the SMTP settings. That worked, but it seems like an old solution and I'd like to understand what it's doing and why it worked.

This is my SMTP setup that gave the `Net::ReadTimeout` error:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'username',
  :password => 'password',
  :domain => 'mydomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 465,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

This is the update that's working.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'username',
  :password => 'password',
  :domain => 'mydomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 465,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  # this line added
  :tls => true
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: Nice overview of TLS itself, but doesn't answer the question in a Rails-context.

Comment: Its literally just documented as ":ssl/:tls - Enables the SMTP connection to use SMTP/TLS (SMTPS: SMTP over direct TLS connection)". What more do you need to know? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Also you're using the wrong port. "For an unencrypted or a TLS connections, use port 25, 2525, or 587" https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/integrating_with_the_smtp_api.html

Comment: `:tls` is for implicit TLS, i.e. `smtps` port 465. STARTTLS is for explicit TLS with `smtp` on port 25 and 587.

Comment: I guess "explicit" means "unencrypted"? That matches up with what you're both saying. It either works using port 465 with the setting or using port 25 without it. Seems strange Sendgrid would use port 465 in their docs but not include the setting. https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/rubyonrails/

Answer (score 2):

> Email is effectively a plaintext communication sent from email clients to receiving email servers or from one server to another.  This design limitation leaves the content of a message in transit open for anyone to eavesdrop; from a wireless hotspot at the airport or coffee shop to your ISP and internet backbone providers that carry your messages throughout the world.
>
> Transport Layer Security (TLS) helps solve this issue by offering encryption technology for your message while it is “in transit” from one secure email server to another. That is, TLS helps prevent eavesdropping on email as it is carried between email servers that have enabled TLS protections for email.  Just as TLS can be used to secure web communications (HTTPS), it can secure email transport. In both applications, TLS has similar strengths and weaknesses. To maximize the content security and privacy, TLS is required between all the servers that handle the message including hops between internal and external servers.
>
> Key features of TLS includes:
>
> - Encrypted messages: TLS uses Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) to encrypt messages from mail server to mail server. This encryption makes it more difficult for hackers to intercept and read messages.
> - Authentication: TLS supports the use of digital certificates to authenticate the receiving servers. Authentication of sending servers is optional. This process verifies that the receivers (or senders) are who they say they are, which helps to prevent spoofing.

[For reference](https://www.internetsociety.org/resources/ota/2017/transport-layered-security-tls-for-email/)

Comment: Any thoughts on the error itself and what it means? The Sendgrid documentation doesn't include the `:tls => true` setting in their setup instructions, so I'd like to make sure I don't have another issue that I'm just patching with this fix.